# Ways to Calculate for a joint density function Var(g(x,y))

Tags: probability

The joint probability density function of X and Y is given by:

(x+y)/8 for 0 < x < 2 0 < y < 2

Calculate the variance of (X + Y)/2.

Can Var(g(x,y)) always/ever be calculated by (f(x)g(x,y)^2)-(f(x,y)g(x,y))^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can grind it out. Let $W=\frac{X+Y}{2}$. We want to calculate $E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$.

The required expectations are both integrals. For example, we have
$$E(W^2)=\int_{x=0}^2 \left(\int_{y=0}^2 \left(\frac{(x+y)^2}{4}\cdot \frac{x+y}{8}\right)\,dy\right)\,dx.$$

The expression for $E(W)$ is similar.

Comment: Had a couple algebra errors. Thanks for the patience, sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: No problem. One could alternately find the density function of $W$, and then calculate the variance.  Because of the shape of the joint density, the density of $W$ turns out to be pleasant. But in this case crude grinding out is probably more efficient.